# Custom Control Property not set

Tags: asp.net, properties, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

In a custom control I put the property

```
[Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(""), Localizable(true), Description("")]
public string InitValue
{
   get { return ViewState["InitValue"].ToString(); }
   set { ViewState["InitValue"] = value; }
}
```

When I include it on a page and run the page I receive the `Object reference not set...` exception. It shoes a line number which is the `get` above.

It happens when I don't set the property, though I don't want the property to be required.

Is it considered a good option to use

```
get { return ViewState["InitValue"]==null ? "" : ViewState["InitValue"].ToString(); }
```

or better to make property into object and `ToString()` it when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Should check the value exist before returning it

```
public string InitValue
{
   get 
   { 
      if(ViewState["InitValue"] != null)
          return ViewState["InitValue"].ToString(); 

      return "default value here";
   }
   set { ViewState["InitValue"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: That's the solution I have in the question. Was hoping for something else.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always handled this is:

```
public string InitValue
{
   get 
   { 
      if(ViewState["InitValue"] == null)
         ViewState["InitValue"] = [DEFAULT VALUE];          

      return ViewState["InitValue"].ToString(); 
   }
   set { ViewState["InitValue"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: That's the same as the solution I have in the question. Was hoping for something else.

Comment: touche! Have you found _another_ way of doing the above? My initial thought is that this is the only way, but I don't want to preclude anything.

Comment: טרם. I hoped maybe the `DefaultValue` attribute would give it a hint, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` is doing a `ToString()` on a nullable property. Handle it and you'll be just fine. In the following code, I have assumed "" as the default value.

```
get { (return ViewState["InitValue"] ?? string.Empty).ToString(); }
```